# Как автоматизировать выгрузку Placemark?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, карты, геолокация, обновление

Есть обычный код для выгрузки Placemark на карту (приложение 1.). Дальше есть тупой код выгрузки с базы (приложение 2.).

Нужно выгрузить Placemark, при помощи ajax. Для этого мне нужно, чтобы вы объяснили, как мне воспользоваться «Определением координат» в Яндекс API.

По логике мне нужно просто получить возможность считывать координаты крайних точек окна отображения карты и передать их в скрипт ajax с целью дальнейшей выгрузки.

[Приложение 1](https://yadi.sk/d/T9knf2KR0OwH_Q)

[Приложение 2](https://yadi.sk/d/RhbFeuubQ3c22Q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете создать карту, подписаться на событие изменения границ карты. После изменения границ карты запросить данные. Этот код будет при каждом изменении слать запросы на сервер за новыми данными:

```
myMap.events.add('boundschange', function(e){
    var bounds = e.get('newBounds');
    // тут запросить данные от сервера и отобразить их
})
```

Дальше вы запросите геолокацию ( В песочнице есть пример определения местоположения пользователя: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation ) и карта при изменении границ карты запросит новые данные от сервера.

Но лучшим вариантом я вижу, создание loading object manager и он сам будет следить за границами карты и делать запросы, вам только нужно будет обработать данные на сервере и вернуть правильно данные. Почитать о нем можно тут: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/loading-object-manager/about-docpage/ Геолокацию запрашиваем как я указал в примере выше.

Comment: Так я произвожу выгрузку из базы данных MySQL и по факту у меня отсутствует серверная реализация! А без неё LOM и ROM не работают! Ну или дайте совет как реализовать серверную часть с учётом что у меня производится расчёт новых координат при парсинге базы данных? Ну или я чего то не догоняю...

Comment: Ну тогда используйте первый вариант. На всякий случай кидаю ещё пример серверной реализации ROM если пойдёте по второму пути https://github.com/dimik/ymaps/tree/master/remote-object-manager-server

Comment: Прости за такую просьбу глупую, но можешь скинуть более подробный пример для первого случая. С учётом работы с MySQL. Просто я прошерстил это и чёт полезного не нашёл ничего. P.S. Не бий!

Comment: А что конкретно не получается? Если нужно реализовать всё, то это уже нужно не сюда, а на фриланс биржу.

Comment: Ну типо как работать с этим ивентом, с привязкой к MySQL. Вот есть у меня код js и куда и на каком этапе использовать данный ивент! Вот я о чём. Типа банально как импортировать этот ивент.

Comment: Ивент использовать после создания карты. Запрашивать данные от сервера внутри ивента.

Comment: Спс огромное разобрался! просто мне нужно выводить 200к меток! Вот и поэтому стараюсь как то ускорить выгрузку